# TTS starts suddenly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk, text-to-speech

I want to make it work tts in a service.
So now it works well. but it has a problem. 
tts started suddenly, after worked.
I'm not sure I think the tts is not well finished. 
But I can't know what is the wrong in the source.
Please tell me

hear is the code.

```
public class servishuo1 extends Service implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
private TextToSpeech mTts;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    super.onCreate();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (mTts != null) {
        mTts.stop();
        mTts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    speakOut();
}

@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) 
    {
        int result = mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) 
        {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } 
        speakOut();
    }
    else 
    {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
    }
private void speakOut() {
    mTts.speak("hello", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One error in you code is here:

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
speakOut();
^^^^^^^^^^^ <---  !!!
```

you should not call `mTts.speak` before onInit callback with TextToSpeech.SUCCESS is called.